# Using rsync with `--include` filters on tens of thousands of files

Tags: rsync

I am trying to copy only the files that match the pattern  `player00_0[1..5]*.*` where `[1..5]` signifies files with a 1,2,3,4, or 5 at that position in the filename.   There are 40K files in the source dir so we can not use any bash `globs` for this job.

Here is my attempt to do that:

```
indir=playout40kem
outdir=visible5k
rsync -am --include='player00_01*.*' --include='player00_02*.*' 
          --include='player00_03*.*' --include='player00_04*.*' 
          --include='player00_05*.*' $indir/ $outdir
```

However the result is that *all* files are copied.  What is the correct way to do this filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582184/66602 The missing piece is:

`--exclude="*"`  . It must *follow* the `include=` entries:

```
rsync -am --include='player00_01*.*' --include='player00_02*.*' 
          --include='player00_03*.*' --include='player00_04*.*' 
          --include='player00_05*.*' --exclude="*" $indir/ $outdir
```

Comment: Character classes/range expressions are allowed in `rsync` patterns and please quote your variables, e.g. `rsync -am --include='player00_0[1-5]*.*' --exclude="*" "$indir"/ "$outdir"`

Comment: @Freddy feel free to make an answer - in particular the use of class/range expressions